# problems with character (') inside string

Tags: javascript, string

The problem I'm having is when a name with " ' "  character is added, I get an error. The error is

```
addLocation({ lat:-11.8445642, lng:-41.221212, name: 'EXAMPLE'S' })
```

The problem is clear to see: in the name property, the string 'EXAMPLE'S' has a " ' " in the middle of the string, which cuts off the end of the string, and it doesn't send this object.
Some of the names that go in this function might have this character.
How do I get it to work, including this character?

I tried the replace method, as it is shown in the function code providen, but it still doesn't work. Maybe I don't know how to use it, or it doesn't work in this case.

```
    function contentBuilder({ name, geometry }) {
        const { location } = geometry

        name.replace(/'/g,"\'");

        return `
            ${name}</br>
            ${location.lat()}</br>
            ${location.lng()}</br>
            <a onclick="addLocation({ lat:${location.lat()}, lng:${location.lng()}, name: '${name}' })" class="map-add-link">Adcionar +</a>
       `
    }
  function addLocation(location) {
        revealLocationSelector('newPlaceMap');

         if(!containLocation(locations,location)){
            locations.push(location);
        }
```

When the function is send, it should give me that error. specified. I should be able to send the object to de addLocation function

Comment: replace does not modify the string directly, it returns the new value, so you need to do something like: `name = name.replace(/'/g,"\'");`

Comment: @AustinGreco Your suggestion has the same effect, that is, none! Try it out

Comment: agreed, stringify is better in this case. Just need to be careful with added quote characters

Comment: Use escaped “ around ${name}. E.g. name: \”${name}\”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never build a JS string yourself. The easiest naive fix is to do `name.replace(/'/g,"\\'")` so that you are escaping the single quote with a backslash. Note that the backslash itself has to be escaped as `\\`.

```
` ... name: '${name.replace(/'/g,"\\'")}' ...`
```

However, that will break if you string contains double quotes or anything else that needs to be escaped such as `\n\b` and you also need to be aware of the type of quote that is enclosing the HTML attribute and you potentially should escape it for HTML to since an extra closing > may break your HTML.

The best thing would be to HTML encode an entire JSON string so that it 
would work in any context and not allow HTML injection which could be susceptible to XSS attacks.

```js
const loc = {
  lat: -11.8445642,
  lng: -41.221212,
  name: "escaped string with <b> that should not show up bold and JS characters \n \r \\ \" '"
};

function htmlEncode(str) {
    return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#39;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

function htmlJsonEncode(obj){
    return htmlEncode(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

document.querySelector("div.output").innerHTML += `
<!-- You should always escape content you have no control of when displaying it as HTML -->
name: ${htmlEncode(loc.name)}<br />
 lat: loc.lat<br />
 long: loc.lng<br />
 <hr />
 <a onclick="console.log(${htmlJsonEncode(loc)})"); return false"
    href="#">Log Object to console using double quotes for HTML attributes</a>
 <hr />
 <a onclick='console.log(${htmlJsonEncode(loc)}); return false'
    href="#">Log Object to console using single quotes for HTML attributes</a>
  `;
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: This almost worked. Works fine for every location that doesn't have a " ' " in the middle of it. Now I get this error:
`addLocation({"lat":-18.8444642,"lng":-48.2525225,"name":"AMORECANA DRINK` it still halves the string. It was supposed to be "DRINK'S" in the end. I made the object as you suggested.

Comment: Also, the first suggestion,  `name: '${JSON.stringify(name)}' ..` doesn't work too. In this case, this happens: `addLocation({ lat:-18.8444642, lng:-48.2525225, name: '`

Comment: @PedroHenriqueBufulindeAlme I'm not sure what didn't work, you should explain it. However, I added an example that shows how it can work in any context.

Answer (score 0):

OK, in this case, what worked for me is:

```
 function contentBuilder({ name, geometry }) {
        const { location } = geometry;
        let nameShow = name;
        name = name.replace(/'/g,"\\'");
        console.log(name);

        return `
            ${nameShow}</br>
            ${location.lat()}</br>
            ${location.lng()}</br>
            <a onclick="addLocation({ lat:${location.lat()}, lng:${location.lng()}, name: '${name}' })" class="map-add-link">Adcionar +</a>
        `
    }
```

I just added another / in the replace function. I don't know why, but it worked like a charm.

Comment: The reason this worked is that you needed to escape the `'` is the string with `\'`, but to do that, you need to escape the backslash also as \\. Note that your code will still break if your string has a double quote, a new line, or anything else that needs to be escaped. You should use what I suggested, I will add HTML escaping so quotes won't mess with the HTML.

Comment: In this case, I only need to handle the `'` because all the location's names added won't ever have a new line or double quotes. Doing what you suggest would be overkill, but I will do it for good practice. Thanks

Comment: If it's good practice, it's not overkill. It's not like it costs you a lot to do it.